# Crystal reports 'If Statement' uses first record for each rows condition

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports, where-clause

I am trying to color cells that contain a certain value in my crystal report cross tab.

In this instance, Any cell that contains a "x" would have a background color of Red. Otherwise it would be Yellow.

This is the syntax I have used in the cell's background formula.

```
if UpperCase({PlaReportEDIT;1.EndedCheck}) = 'X' then 
    crRed
else
    crYellow
```

I think my report is basing the coloring of each row on the 1st record, because if the 1st record is X then it highlights all the rows Red, otherwise all of them Yellow.

I am trying to figure out how to conditionally format the if statement so it looks for the x Value on each row for that rows Background color, as oppose to just looking at the 1st rows which it appears to be doing at the moment.

I have searched the web but cannot find a solution to my problem.

If anyone has any tips or advice it would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is 'Highlight expert' for crosstab cells coloring - right-click on appropriate cell and you should see (at least in some CR versions it is located there).

Comment: this has worked, if you want to post as answer I will accept,. @Arvo

Answer (score 0):

There is 'Highlight expert' for crosstab cells coloring - right-click on appropriate cell and you should see (at least in some CR versions it is located there).